# Python/OpenCV webcam movement backwards

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

I am not sure what the issue is but when I move around on the webcam it captures my face but it is not a mirror of my movements, it is backwards/inverted.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
def Webcam(webcam, classifier, downScale):
        
        if webcam.isOpened():
                rval, frame = webcam.read()
        else:
                rval = False

        while rval:
                # detect faces and draw bounding boxes
                minisize = (frame.shape[1]/downScale,frame.shape[0]/downScale)
                miniframe = cv2.resize(frame, minisize)
                faces = classifier.detectMultiScale(miniframe)
                for f in faces:
                        x, y, w, h = [ v*downScale for v in f ]
                        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255))
         
                cv2.putText(frame, "Press ESC to close.", (5, 25),
                                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, (255,255,255))
                cv2.imshow("Face Crop", frame)
         
                # get next frame
                rval, frame = webcam.read()
         
                key = cv2.waitKey(10)
                if key in [27, ord('Q'), ord('q')]: # exit on ESC
                        break
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

a camera is not a mirror.

but you can easily [flip()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#cv2.flip) it to behave like a mirror:

```
rval, frame = webcam.read()
frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)
```

Comment: This is a the right concept but for some reason it is not working for me... I did narrow it down to being an X-Axis issue as the Y-Axis is correct. Could the issue be that I am using a front facing camera on a laptop? Or do I have to pass in a dst value?

Answer (score -1):

`rval, frame = webcam.read()`

`frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)`

In `cv2.flip()` argument try using 0 if you want to flip in y axis, 1 if you want to flip in x axis and -1 if want to flip in both axes.

It's clearly mentioned in documentation provided by @berak [flip()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#cv2.flip)